# Is there a way to pass a method reference in Java?

Tags: java, function, methods, reference, parameters

This is quite difficult to phrase, but I need to be able to link a specific method to an object. More specifically, I'm making a graphics-oriented GUI, and I want to be able to assign an arbitrary method as the default "action" function for an element, such as a button.

That is, I created these interfaced "graphics" objects that basically have the ability to draw themselves. I would like them to handle their own actions, so I can, for example, do something like this:

```
GraphicObject b1 = new Button();
GraphicObject b2 = new Button();
b1.assignDefaultAction(---some method reference here--);
b2.assignDefaultAction(---a different method reference here--);
```

Then, if I do something like:

```
b1.action();
b2.action();
```

Each element will call its own referenced method independently. I believe this is possible to do in C++, but I haven't seen it in Java. Is it even possible, or is there some kind of a workaround? The thing I'm trying to avoid is having to create specific abstraction for every single little thing I need to do, or litter my containing JPanel with a hundred specifications that just look messy.

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buttons should use `ActionListener` implementations.  Stick with Swing in that particular case.

Your own classes can follow suit and start with a Command pattern interface:

```
public interface Command {
    public void execute(Map<String, Object> parameters); 
}
```

Or maybe a better idea is to stick with the API that the JDK provides and try [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).

Answer (score 1):

There are no method references in Java. Instead you can use pseudo-closures (aka anonymous inner classes). The only problem with this is of course, you can't reuse the functions if needed.

Comment: Not true. Java has a Method object - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html  However, as duffymo mentioned, you probably want to use ActionListeners instead.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure I would equate a reflected Method to a method reference. You still need an instance of its containing class in order to invoke it. Also, it would be hard (impossible?) to enforce the method signature if you used reflected Method class.

Comment: Agreed - which is why an ActionListener would be the preferred solution.

Comment: I'm neither for nor against ActionListeners. My answer is for the first part of the OP's question `Is there a way to pass a method reference in Java`.

Comment: BTW, Groovy offers an interesting solution - even though it's a dynamic language, it provides the ability (through Meta Programming) to cache method pointers, so that the performance of invoking a dynamic method after the first invocation is approximately as performant as direct native invocation of the method. See for example, http://www.justinspradlin.com/programming/groovy-metaprogramming-creating-behavior-on-the-fly/

Comment: And in the new JDK 7, we have invokeDynamic, which makes use of "method handles" - see http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/DynTypeLang/

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd just use an ActionListener anonymous inner class to do this, and add whatever method calls you want in the actionPerformed method.

Something like:

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        b.someMethod();
    }               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with **Java 8** there will be easy-to-use method references and lambda expressions.

Assigning actions to buttons is actually a prime example.

```
 bttnExit.setOnAction((actionEvent) -> { Platform.exit(); });
```

or, using method references:

```
 bttnExit.setOnAction(MyClass::handleExitButton);
```