# Is there a way to pass a method reference in Java?

Tags: java, swing, customization, layout-manager

First of all, this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338193/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-method-reference-in-java), even though they have the same title.  That question was referring to passing methods that were essentially the same as C functions: they didn't need to belong to a particular object.  In that case, you can pass a `Runnable` or `Callable` object.

Instead, I am asking the following: is it possible to pass a reference to a particular method in a class, and have the method called for a particular object?

As an example, I was looking at the code for the `FlowLayout` in Swing, and noticed that the `preferredLayoutSize` and `minimumLayoutSize` implementations were exactly the same, except for one line:

```
public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container target) {
  synchronized (target.getTreeLock()) {
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
    int nmembers = target.getComponentCount();
    boolean firstVisibleComponent = true;
    boolean useBaseline = getAlignOnBaseline();
    int maxAscent = 0;
    int maxDescent = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < nmembers ; i++) {
        Component m = target.getComponent(i);
        if (m.isVisible()) {
            Dimension d = m.getPreferredSize();
            dim.height = Math.max(dim.height, d.height);
            if (firstVisibleComponent) {
                firstVisibleComponent = false;
            } else {
                dim.width += hgap;
            }
            dim.width += d.width;
            if (useBaseline) {
                int baseline = m.getBaseline(d.width, d.height);
                if (baseline >= 0) {
                    maxAscent = Math.max(maxAscent, baseline);
                    maxDescent = Math.max(maxDescent, d.height - baseline);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (useBaseline) {
        dim.height = Math.max(maxAscent + maxDescent, dim.height);
    }
    Insets insets = target.getInsets();
    dim.width += insets.left + insets.right + hgap*2;
    dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom + vgap*2;
    return dim;
  }
}

public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container target) {
  synchronized (target.getTreeLock()) {
    boolean useBaseline = getAlignOnBaseline();
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
    int nmembers = target.getComponentCount();
    int maxAscent = 0;
    int maxDescent = 0;
    boolean firstVisibleComponent = true;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < nmembers ; i++) {
        Component m = target.getComponent(i);
        if (m.visible) {
            Dimension d = m.getMinimumSize();
            dim.height = Math.max(dim.height, d.height);
            if (firstVisibleComponent) {
                firstVisibleComponent = false;
            } else {
                dim.width += hgap;
            }
            dim.width += d.width;
            if (useBaseline) {
                int baseline = m.getBaseline(d.width, d.height);
                if (baseline >= 0) {
                    maxAscent = Math.max(maxAscent, baseline);
                    maxDescent = Math.max(maxDescent,
                                          dim.height - baseline);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (useBaseline) {
        dim.height = Math.max(maxAscent + maxDescent, dim.height);
    }

    Insets insets = target.getInsets();
    dim.width += insets.left + insets.right + hgap*2;
    dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom + vgap*2;
    return dim;
  }
}
```

The `preferredLayoutSize` method calls the `preferredLayoutSize` method of `m` (the `i`-th component), whereas `minimumLayoutSize` calls the `minimumLayoutSize` method of `m`.  As far as I can see, the two methods are otherwise identical.

As any [programmer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) will tell you, code duplication is a bad thing.  In this case, however, it's not obvious how to get rid of duplicated code.  It's clear that there ought to be a private method with the code in it that both public methods call, passing in a reference to the `preferredLayoutSize` and `minimumLayoutSize` methods of the `Component` class.  In C I could do that using function pointers, so it makes sense that there should be some way of doing it in Java.  Passing in a `Runnable` or `Callable` almost works, but neither returns a value.  **Edit:** This is wrong.  The overridden method in a `Callable` *does* return a value, and the object it's acting on can be passed in as a parameter.

Now that I've typed all that out, a solution occurs to me: you could write an `interface` with a method called `Dimension layoutSize(Component comp)` and write two implementations, one of which returned `comp.preferredLayoutSize()` and the other of which returned `comp.minimumLayoutSize()`.  You could then write a private method taking an instance of that interface as a parameter, and use that to run the separate methods at the right point in the code.  You could even use anonymous inner classes so you didn't have to write a new class for each type of layout size.  It still seems like quite a lot of trouble for a fairly simple problem, though.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: With reflection, look up the `Method` class. You will need to also have a reference to an object to `invoke()` it on.

Comment: I guess with Java 8 it is possible.

Comment: Or, even better, use a [`MethodHandle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) .

Comment: Doesn't passing a `Callable` still apply? Your code in the `Callable` would call the relevant method on your object.

Comment: Code duplication isn't good, but it's worse when people go to great lengths just because they think code duplication is a _horrible_ thing. Then you come up with convoluted unreadable "solutions" where the duplicated code is removed, but the remaining code looks like a madman wrote it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, you're right.  I misremembered that the overridden method in a `Callable` didn't return a value, but now I see that that that's not true at all.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 please whats goal, maybe is there another simler way, starting with JComponents tree from ZOrder, not clear for why reason(s) you are PreferredSizes hunter (and I hope that there is consequence wtih revalidate & repaint)

Comment: @mKorbel I'm trying to write my own implementation of `LayoutManager`, and so I'm looking at existing implementations for help.  When I come to implement `preferredLayoutSize` and `minimumLayoutSize`, I'd like to avoid the code duplication I saw in `FlowLayout`.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 yes agree, but why reinvent the wheel from zero...., have look (before) at attempts by camickr and StanislavL(theirs blogs)

Comment: @Donkey_2009 not are methods are public, then I'm not sure if isn't Reflection only one of ways, much luck ... +1

Comment: @mKorbel When you say 'reinvent the wheel', are you referring to my desire to implement my own layout manager?  In that case, see my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784473/how-can-i-extend-flowlayout-so-components-are-sized-to-take-up-as-much-space-as

Comment: @Donkey_2009 some of people here aren't nice and with pace_full_face, valid for me too :-)

Comment: @Kayaman I agree that sometimes programmers go to ridiculous lengths to obey some "commandment" that they don't really understand the reason for.  In this case, my question would be: "Suppose someone later decides the algorithm in `preferredLayoutSize` is wrong or needs to be modified to support a new feature; what's the chance that the same change needs to be made to `minimumLayoutSize`, and what's the chance that they'll forget to?"  I think the chance is high enough here to make the extra rigmarole worthwhile.

Comment: @ajb Exactly. Just because you happen to have the same code in two places doesn't mean that they're equal in every aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap one of the methods in a class `LayoutSizing` (maybe a local class), with an abstract method for the calculation on `m`, with `m` as parameter and then in both methods instantiate `new LayoutSizing() { @Override ... }` with the method implemented.

In Java 8 this will then hopefully sill be a bit nicer looking.

Comment: Any reason for using an abstract class rather than an interface?

Comment: @Donkey_2009 for the code, the original method content. In Java 8 it could indeed be an interface with a `default` method if I understood, and hence be eligible for the functional notation.

Comment: Mind, the answer of @ajb is what one sees more often; a private method `commonCode` with an extra parameter, an interface that implements the inner calculation. One then has an extra method, so I wanted to mention this solution.

Comment: Yeah, well that's what I suggested in my question.  I think this is marginally cleaner, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an interface:

```
interface DimensionReturningThingy {
    public Dimension getDim (Component c);
}

public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container target) {
    commonCode (target, new DimensionReturningThingy () {
        public Dimension getDim (Component m) {
            return m.getPreferredSize ();
        });
}

// and similarly for minimumLayoutSize

public Dimension commonCode (Container target, DimensionReturningThingy drt) {

// now repeat code above, except that replace

        Dimension d = m.getPreferredSize();

// with

        Dimension d = drt.getDim (m);
```

I'm not good at naming things, so I'm sure you can come up with better names for some of these.

Edit: I think I was working on answering this before you edited your original post to mention the interface solution.

Comment: Yes thanks.  You can also use the `Callable` interface instead of `DimensionReturningThingy`, since it's already there.

Comment: Since `Callable.call()` doesn't take any arguments, how would this work?  If `commonCode` took a `Callable` instead of a `DimensionReturningThingy`, how would `commonCode` get the `m` argument passed to the called method?  Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see off the top of my head how this would work.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  For some reason, I thought that the overridden method in `Callable` could take parameters.

Comment: It seems like a variant of `Callable<V>` that takes an `Object...` variable argument list might be useful just to have around, although you'd lose type safety in the arguments...

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case, the simplest solution is to refactor this 2 methods in three:

```
private Dimension layoutSize(Container target, boolean prederred) {
    ...
    Dimension d = prederred?m.getPreferredSize():m.minimumLayoutSize();
    ...
}

public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container target) {
    return layoutSize(target, true);
}

public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container target) {
    return layoutSize(target, false);
}
```